# Unable to find Windows Forms App (.NET Core) Template. Where is it located?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

Following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a66wsCRSgDk&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oV7n106SEWwWPy4WVjpl3Fj) on the official YouTube dotNET channel, I am unable to find the Windows Forms App (.NET Core) Template under Create Projects.

I have downloaded [Visual Studio 2022 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)

I have installed it.

I have downloaded [Download .NET Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1)

I have installed it.

I have opened Visual Studio, clicked Tools menu, Options... then I checked:

[image: image1]

I then close Visual Studio 2022 Preview and re-open it.

Upon reopening it, under **Create New Project** all I see is:

[image: example1]

And when I click at the bottom, "**Not finding what you're looking for? Install more tools and features**", I see:

[image: example2]

Comment: Did you install .NET core tooling inside VS? Normally you don't install .NET Core from the webpage but rather from the VS Installer. I don't see any .NET Core in the "Installation details" in your screenshot (the runtime is *not* what you want, you want the SDK)

Comment: What is ".NET core tooling" specifically called? Is it found under Individual components? What do I need to click where in order to show this check box?

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't tried the 2022 Preview, in 2019 is under "Other toolsets" and it's called ".NET cross-platform development". You can check under Individual components for .NET/.NET Core SDK items

Comment: @suchislife: The downvote (which I did NOT cast) is probably for not even trying to solve your own problem by selecting the best match and seeing what happened.  That is, after all, what Ian did to determine that there is a dropdown in a later step of the wizard.

Comment: I certainly didn't think it was you, Camilo or Ben. Looking for the absence of something by concluding it is found in the next step was not intuitive to me.. But I have added it to my list of things to try.

Comment: The anser by Ian makes a lot of sense. Don't know why I just skipped those images when I suggested looking at options in the VS installer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are **two** branches of .NET: Framework and "new" .NET/.NET Core.
2. In the dialogs shown, all items are repeated **twice**. One of those items has " (.NET Framework)" appended to its description, the other has nothing extra.
3. By deductive logic then, of the **two** items shown, the one for .NET/.NET Core **is the one that is not for .NET Framework**.

And indeed, if you select the plain-Jane "Windows Forms App", the wizard prompts you to select a framework from a dropdown that only includes .NET/.NET Core frameworks.